# Summing list of lists in Raku

Tags: arrays, raku, rakudo

I am trying to sum a list of lists in Raku. Example taken from [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/statistics.py#L168):

```
my $arr = ([1e50, 1, -1e50] xx 1000);

say (flat |$arr).sum; # output 0

# https://docs.raku.org/language/operators#infix_xx
# https://docs.raku.org/routine/flat
```

It outputs `0` which is not what was expected (1000). However, this works right

```
say ([1, 2] xx 5).flat.sum;
```

Why is behavior different? Is it due to precision?

Another thing is

```
my $arr = ([1e50, 1, -1e50] xx 1000);
my @array = $arr.flat;
```

how can I make every element of this flattened list to `float` efficiently?

One way I know is iterating every element of this list and calling `Num` method.

```
my $arr = [1, 2] xx 5; #([1e50, 1, -1e50] xx 10);

my @array = $arr.flat;
for @array {$_=$_.Num};
```

Comment: You can make `[1e50, 1, -1e50]` be three floats by writing it as `[1e50, 1e0, -1e50]`. (I imagine you're asking about variables, not literals, and that most readers will know or be able to guess what I've noted, but I thought I'd comment just in case.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your first question: yes, it's precision, as you're forcing it to using floating point arithmetic, and the `1` is drowned out.

```
my @a = |(10**50, 1, -10**50) xx 1000;
say @a.sum;  # 1000
```

Using `10**50` allows Raku to keep using (large) integer arithmetic.

To ensure all elements in an array are floating points, you can add a coercing constraint to your array definition:

```
my Num() @a = |(10**50, 1, -10**50) xx 1000;
say @a.sum;  # 0, as the 1's get drowned out again
```

Comment: This seems to work: `my Rat() @a = |(1e50, 1, -1e50) xx 1000;
say sum(@a) # 1000`

Comment: Indeed, because 1e50 is still within the `Rat`'s precision.